# Django - Como interagir 2 formularios

Tags: html, python, django

No form1 eu tenho essa entrada "name_car". Esse formulario salva normalmente no banco de dados.
No form2 tenho o mesmmo campo "name_car" para colocar as "peças".
Dúvida: Como trazer o nome do carro do form1 para o campo do form2, sem precisar selecionar no field.

no models.py estão relacionados.

models.py

```
class car(models.Model):
    name_car= models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    nome_model= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({})".format(nome_car, self.nome_model)

class parts(models.Model):
    name_car = models.ForeignKey(car, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="parts")
    ns_parts = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome_car.nome_car
```

views.py do manual2

```
class PartsNewView(CreateView):
    template_name = ' Parts/parts.html' 
    model = parts
    def get_queryset(self):  
            return parts.objects.filter(name_car_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
    def get_success_url(self) -> str:
        messages.success(self.request, 'A parte do carro foi Cadastrado com sucesso')
        return reverse_lazy('car')
```

```
form1 
<form method="post">
 {% render_field form.name_car class="form-control" type="text" %}
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Register</button>
</form> 
save.

in form2
form2
<form method="post">
 <!-- Doubt: what rule do I use to bring form1's car name to form2's field. -->  
 {% render_field form.name_car value="{{ object.name_car }}" class="form-control" type="text" %}
  
 <br>
 {% render_field form.parts class="form-control" type="text" %}  
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-2">Add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Subscrever os metodos get e post tanto o View ou CreateView
assim como utilizou o get_queryset e  get_success_url,
havendo uma ForeignKey, tera que repassar ela para outro form diretamente.

```
   class ItenABVIEW(View):
        template_name = 'superforms.html'
    
        def get(self, request):
            formulario1 = ItemAForms()
            formulario2 = ItemBForms()
            contexto = {'formulario1':formulario1,'formulario2':formulario2}
    
            return render(request, self.template_name, contexto)
    
        def post(self,request):
            formulario1 = ItemAForms(request.POST or None)
            formulario2 = ItemBForms(request.POST or None)
            # No caso é uma chave tera que pegar ela
            if formulario1.is_valid() and formulario2.is_valid() :
                chave = ItemA(itema=formulario1.data['itema'])
                chave.save()
                ItemB(itemb=formulario2.data['itemb'], itemdeFora_id=chave.pk).save()
                formulario1 = ItemAForms()
                formulario2 = ItemBForms()
    
            contexto = {'formulario1': formulario1, 'formulario2': formulario2}
    
    
            return render(request, self.template_name,contexto)
```

no html os dois form no mesmo post:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>A</title>
</head>
<body>


      <form  method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formulario1 }}
          {{ formulario2 }}
          

    <button type="submit">save</button>
      </form>
```

Comment: Não entendi seu codigo. Voce juntou os formularios ? 
No meu caso são formularios separados um em casa template. mas no madels.py com conectados por uma foreignkey.
exemplo: tela de cadastro do primeiro form1 onde coloco nome do carro e nome do modelo e salvo. depois de salvo eu clico nesse carro cadastrado e dentro tem um botão "peças" onde adiciona as pessas desse carro. Quando clica no botao aparece um formulario form2 com campo "nome do carro" e "nome da peça" o campo nome do carro deveria trazer já o nome do carro. entende. ?

Comment: Use o field lookups, uma query no form2  que retorna o campo name_car do model car. o que escrevi foi  um único formulário que colocar as característica do carro e a peça dele em uma unica pagina, não é assim. usa uma consulta lookups pode recuperar o valor da tabela name_car do model 1 mas usando a query no model2,https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups